# Animated Button In Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make animated buttons in Tkinter. The buttons have a command when they get clicked they get bigger or smaller depending on if someone clicked another button.

```
from tkinter import*

screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("500x500")


def Test_clicked():
    Testing_Button.config(width=6)
    Testing_Button2.config(width=5)
def Test2_clicked():
    Testing_Button.config(width=5)
    Testing_Button2.config(width=6)


Testing_Button = Button(width=5,height=5, command=Test_clicked)
Testing_Button.place(x=0,y=0)

Testing_Button2 = Button(width=5,height=5, command=Test2_clicked)
Testing_Button2.place(x=0,y=90)








screen.mainloop()
```

When I run the file everything works but if I add more buttons that just makes my code longer and messier. I wanted to know if there is a thing like "FocusIn" for a button instead of Entry.

Comment: I basically want Toggle Buttons

Comment: It sounds like you want to make it so you have *n* number of buttons but only one function to call that would modify the rest of the button sizes. One thought is creating a lambda function (ex. `command=lambda: on_click(widget_name)`, or bind a left-click callback, same idea) that will modify every button except for the given one, changing the widths

Comment: Please edit your answer instead of leaving a comment.

Comment: Or, if you're looking for toggle buttons, it might be clearer to the user if, instead of changing the width, set `state=tk.DISABLED` on the button (unclickable, greyed out)

Comment: _" I wanted to know if there is a thing like "FocusIn" for a button instead of Entry"_ - yes, all widgets support `<FocusIn>` and `<FocusOut>`. However, buttons aren't going to get focus by default. They also support `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` for when the mouse pointer goes in and out of the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have *n* buttons, just provide the name of the button as a parameter. Just include lambda while passing it as the command of the button. If this is implemented, your code would look like this:

```py
from tkinter import*

screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("500x500")

prev_button = None 

def Test_clicked(button):
    global prev_button 
    
    button.config(width=6)
    try:
        prev_button.config(width=5)
        prev_button = button
    except:
        prev_button = button

Testing_Button = Button(width=5,height=5, command=lambda: Test_clicked(Testing_Button))
Testing_Button.place(x=0,y=0)

Testing_Button2 = Button(width=5,height=5, command=lambda: Test_clicked(Testing_Button2))
Testing_Button2.place(x=0,y=90)

screen.mainloop()
```

Also, in your code you are using from tkinter import *, which is a bad habit. Also include spaces before and after operators(equal sign and others) to improve readability